# MSSQL How to run a query for each of a known set set of ID's

Tags: sql-server, loops, foreach, static

A basic query to delete a row from a table for a list of known values (values can't be found with a query) might be:

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN (1, 4, 6, 7)

In this case, table1 has dependencies, so I'd like to write into the query other relationships that need to be deleted first, based on the list (1, 4, 6, 7). So, I might have something like:

DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id_table2 in (1, 4, 6, 7)

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN (1, 4, 6, 7)

But I want to have a query that declares the fixed list and have the query execute for each value? (pseudo code)

[fixed list] = (1, 4, 6, 7...) (allowing any # of static entries)

DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id_table2 in ([fixed list])

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN ([fixed list])

Comment: Are you trying to delete records from two tables where there is a certain ID?

Comment: Chris -- no -- the 2nd or 3rd table would have a foreign key. So, the item in table 2 would be deleted because another column links in (1,4,6,7) from the first table.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH FixedList (ID) AS
(SELECT 1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4 UNION ALL
 SELECT 6 UNION ALL
 SELECT 7)

DELETE FROM table1 where id in 
  (SELECT ID FROM FixedList)

DELETE FROM table2 where id in
  (select ID FROM FixedList)

-- OPTION 2
 CREATE TABLE #FixedList
  (ID As integer)

 INSERT INTO #Fixedlist
 VALUES (1),
        (4),
        (6),
        (7)
DELETE FROM table1 where id in 
  (SELECT ID FROM #FixedList)

DELETE FROM table2 where id in
  (select ID FROM #FixedList)
 --
```

Comment: So -- there's no way to do it with something like (forgive the psuedo stuff):

WITH list (ID) in (1,4,6,7,8,9,10,13, ...) -- I just would like to avoid (if possible) having to continue adding copies of:

(SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
....
SELECT 35 UNION ALL)

No way to give a list it can just loop through to fill the needed values?

Comment: If gave you another option if you want to reuse the list.

Comment: You could use dynamic sql but that would be harder